# Excel macro to find weekend from day number

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro which calculates no. of hours spent on a task for each day in a month.

The first row contains day numbers from 1 to 31 and data is filled using the macro accordingly for each day number for a month. The sheet name contains the month name.

Now, the problem is the macro leaves blank for the days for which data is not available. That day can be a Saturday, Sunday, or the person was absent that day.

I want the macro to identify weekends and highlight those with gray color so that only absent days appear as blank.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting for this?

Answer (score 2):

**Using cell formulas and conditional formatting** (VBA below)

You could do this quite easily with the built-in `WEEKDAY` cell formula, together with the `DATE` formula.

By setting up the year and month value in the sheet, you can create an extra column which gives the day of the week as a number between 1 and 7:

```
=WEEKDAY(DATE($A$2, $B$2,C2))
```

[image: weekday formula]

---

Then you can set up conditional formatting to colour days 7 and 1 (Saturday and Sunday respectively) grey

[image: conditional formatting]

---

**Using VBA**

You can apply the same logic as above, but from a sub. This doesn't require the month and year values to be stored in the sheet, and takes the month from the sheet name. It then directly colours the day number grey if on the weekend.

```
Sub weekdayhighlight()
    Dim days As Range
    Set days = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C8") ' Range where date numbers are stored, 1,2,...,31
    Dim month As String
    month = ActiveSheet.Name ' Active sheet name is "May"
    Dim day As Range
    Dim daynum As Long
    ' Loop over days to test for weekday
    For Each day In days
        ' Get day number, from date in format "1 May, 2017"
        daynum = Weekday(DateValue(day.Value & " " & month & ", 2017"), firstdayofweek:=vbSunday)
        If daynum = 7 Or daynum = 1 Then
            day.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)  ' Grey for saturdays or sundays
        End If
    Next day
End Sub
```

**Note:** This macro will throw an error if you try and compute the weekday of a non-existant date, for instance the 31st of Feb. You say each sheet has day numbers from 1 to 31, you should limit that to actual existing dates or add error handling to the code.

Answer (score -1):

Try combining your sheet name and column headers into date (what about a year?) in a loop and then use DatePart() function to determine whether it is weekend day or not. It would be easier if column headers were real dates (may be formatted to show day only).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16072534)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this IS an answer, it describes how to approach the goal. Should I write code instead? This is not what SO is made for - note rain did not provide any code to check. And last not least Wolfies' answer codes exactly what I wrote.

Comment: No, giving a vague hint is not an answer. An answer in this case would at least contain a (partial) solution in code, or a more detailed explanation.